# Returning a float value in a C function

Tags: c, return

First semester of CS. 
When I change "%d" to "%f" the output is 10 times worse, not even showing the KPH row. Really not sure what I am doing wrong other than that. 
This is a screenie of what happens as it is now.

Thanks for halpz I am n00b

```
#include<stdio.h>

float convertToMPH(float KPH);
float convertToKPH(float MPH);

int main(void){

    int i;

    puts("Kilometers per hour converted to miles per hour:");
    puts("Kph\tMph");


    for(i=185; i>=0; i-=5){
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, convertToMPH(i));
    }
}

float convertToMPH(float KPH){
return (float) (KPH / 1.609344); 

}
```

[image: http://i63.tinypic.com/24mhmk3.png]

Comment: @Himanshu OP said that he tried that but didn't get expected output.

Comment: in function `convertToMPH` you are having argument type `float` while in loop you are passing `int`. try `convertToMPH((float)i)`.

Comment: @ameyCU, see OP's comment in given answer. Problem was same as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Himanshu Then OP's question is misleading as he mentioned _"When I change "%d" to "%f" the output is 10 times worse,"_ .

Comment: I was changing both instances of "%d" instead of just one. For some reason I had spaced that one is an int and the other is a float. Honestly it was a dumb mistake but after staring at it for an hour the issue only seemed to further escape me. Thank you all for your help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 printf("%d\t%d\n", i, convertToMPH(i));
```

to

```
 printf("%d\t%f\n", i, convertToMPH(i));
```

Comment: WOW. I feel dumb. Thank you so much.